# WCF + Thread, cant .Open() out of the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, named-pipes

So I have a service interface (IServiceContract) and its implementation (ServiceContract)

In my client I create an instance of this on the constructor of the client.

```
Service.ServiceContractClient objProxy; //This is the server instance
myCallbacks = new ClientBase(new InstanceContext(this));
objProxy = new Service.ServiceContractClient(new InstanceContext(myCallbacks), "1");
```

So I should be able to do a `objProxy.Open()` at every moment.

But to start the communication, it is done through a thread that does a handshake.
Handshake is a wcf method in the server, called from the client.

So if I do the Open out of the thread, it will say that it is faulted and not let me do it

If I put it inside, it will work, but that is not correct, it should be out.

The thread is just a mechanism to sleep my client in a connected mode.

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        objClientThread = new Thread(start) { IsBackground = true };
        objClientThread.Start();
    }

    private void start()
    {
            if (performHandshake())
            {
                IsConnected = true;
                while (IsConnected)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
     }


    private Boolean performHandshake()
    {
            objProxy.Open();
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is Performing handshake...", Name));
            string xmlConfig = objProxy.Handshake(Name, ModuleType, RecordTypes, Description, Version);
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} is loading configuration...", Name));
            objConfiguration.LoadXml(xmlConfig as String);
            try
            {
                if (OnHandshakeCompleted != null)
                    OnHandshakeCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            //Handshake successfull
            return true;
    }
```

How can I put the Open out of the thread and make it work inside the thread (I can call it but it will say it is in a faulted state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally putted on the `start()` method and it worked.